# Confusion with how the bounty works

Tags: support, bounties

I have recently taken a look into bounties, yet one thing has started to ponder me.

**I see an awful lot of users with very low reputation with 50+ bounty questions**, am I missing something?

I have looked into [how it works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) and this has simply confused the matter further.

*How can users with >50 bounty or even >75 for that matter be able to set bounties?* Especially when they do not have enough reputation to even cover that bounty.

An example of this would be: [This user has 47 rep, and has a 50+ bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941696/visualstatemanager-on-listbox)

Comment: He had 97 then before placing the bounty. Place a bounty and the rep is deducted immediately.

Comment: I see, but this isn't shown as a deduction in his rep score table?

Comment: The reputation is being decreased the moment you set the bounty, not after it's awarded, guess that's what confused you.

Comment: @PhilipGullick It is. June 18th -50 bounty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bounty amount is deducted from the reputation, immediately. The reputation you see is *after* the bounty amount has been taken off.

So, if you see a user with 47 rep who has a 50 rep bounty - they has 97 rep before they started the bounty. As soon as they started the 50 rep bounty their rep dropped to 47.

Does that make it clear?

Comment: As stated in the "how it works" post: *"The bounty award will be subtracted from your reputation when the bounty is started, not when it is awarded."*

Comment: @Bart - we are actually adding words to that effect to the start bounty popup.

Comment: Stop improving things! We'll have nothing to complain about if it continues like this.

Comment: @Bart - likely story.

Comment: @Bart, there is *always* something to complain about. Assume there isn't, we can complain about not having anything to complain about.

Comment: @doubleDown I like your style.